# Not understanding the reason for not getting full rank matrix

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I have a structure shown in figure. It has four members. Each member has represented by two displacement field $W_i$ and $U_i$. I have expressed this displacement field using some functions. I found out the potential energy $v_i$ and kinetic energy $t_i$ associated with these members. Na I have add them together to form total potential energy $V$ and total kinetic energy $T$. Using this total energy I have constructed Lagrangian $Lg$ of this system. I have clearly mentioned the direction of the displacement of these functions using arrows in the figure. To satisfy this displacement  I have imposed some kinematic constraints at the location $Z_i$. These are $W_1(x=z_i)=U_{1+i}(x=\gamma)$ , $U_1(x=z_i)=W_{1+i}(x=\gamma)$ and $\frac{dW_1(x=z_i)}{dx}=\frac{dW_{i+1}(x=\gamma)}{dx}$. These constraints are added in the Lagrangian $Lg$. The modified $Lg$ is minimized with respect to unknown constants (for $W_{i}$ these are $a,b,c,d$) (for $U_{i}$ these are $e,f,g,h$) and the kinematic constraints are imposed with some unknow constants $\lambda_{i},\alpha_i,\beta_{i}$. After minimization, I formed the matrix out of it. I checked The Rank of the matrix it is coming as 16. But the size of the matrix is 17. I don't know what mistake I am doing.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

Y = 2*^11;
ρ = 7850;
aa = 0.1*0.1;
Iyy = 0.1^4/12;
L1 = 4;

z[1] = L1/4;
z[2] = (2*L1)/4;
z[3] = (3*L1)/4;

γ = 0.5*L1;

k = 1;
beta1 = {1.8751, 4.69409, 7.85476, 10.9955, 14.1372, 17.2788};
mm = Table[((Cos[β*x] - 
        Cosh[β*
          x]) - (((Cos[β*γ] + 
           Cosh[β*γ])/(Sin[β*γ] + 
           Sinh[β*γ]))*(Sin[β*x] - 
          Sinh[β*x]))) /. {β -> beta1[[i]]/γ}, {i, 
    1, k}];
nn = Table[((Cos[β*x] - 
        Cosh[β*
          x]) - (((Cos[β*L1] + 
           Cosh[β*L1])/(Sin[β*L1] + 
           Sinh[β*L1]))*(Sin[β*x] - 
          Sinh[β*x]))) /. {β -> beta1[[i]]/L1}, {i, 1, k}];

beamV = Flatten[{nn}];

varbeam1 = Table[Subscript[a, i], {i, 1, k}];
W[1] = Total[Table[Subscript[a, i]*beamV[[i]], {i, 1, k}]];
W1xx = Expand[D[W[1], {x, 2}]];
v[1] = 0.5*Y*Iyy*Integrate[Expand[(W1xx)^2], {x, 0, L1}]
t[1] = 0.5*ρ*aa*ω^2 Integrate[Expand[(W[1])^2], {x, 0, L1}]


varbeam2 = Table[Subscript[b, i], {i, 1, k}];
W[2] = Total[Table[Subscript[b, i]*beamV[[i]], {i, 1, k}]];
W2xx = Expand[D[W[2], {x, 2}]];
v[2] = 0.5*Y*Iyy*Integrate[Expand[(W2xx)^2], {x, 0, γ}]
t[2] = 0.5*ρ*
  aa*ω^2 Integrate[Expand[(W[2])^2], {x, 0, γ}]

W[3] = W[2] /. b -> c;
W[4] = W[2] /. b -> d;

varbeam3 = varbeam2 /. b -> c;
varbeam4 = varbeam2 /. b -> d;

v[3] = v[2] /. b -> c;
v[4] = v[2] /. b -> d;

t[3] = t[2] /. b -> c;
t[4] = t[2] /. b -> d;

soft = Table[Sin[((2*i + 1)*π*x)/(2*L1)], {i, 0, 0}];
barH = Flatten[{soft}];

Table[Plot[barH[[ i]], {x1, 0, γ}], {i, 1, Length[barH]}];

U[1] = Expand[
  Total[Table[Subscript[e, i]*barH[[i]], {i, 1, Length[barH]}]]]
varbar1 = Table[Subscript[e, i], {i, 1, Length[barH]}];
U1x = Expand[D[U[1], {x, 1}]];

v[5] = 0.5*aa*Y (Integrate[Expand[(U1x)^2], {x, 0, L1}])
t[5] = 0.5*ρ*
  aa*ω^2*(Integrate[Expand[(U[1])^2], {x, 0, L1}])

vbsf = Table[Sin[((2*i + 1)*π*x)/(2*γ)], {i, 0, 0}];
barV = Flatten[{vbsf}];

Table[Plot[barV[[ i]], {x, 0, γ}], {i, 1, Length[barV]}];

U[2] = Expand[
  Total[Table[Subscript[f, i]*barV[[i]], {i, 1, Length[barV]}]]]
varbar2 = Table[Subscript[f, i], {i, 1, Length[barV]}];
U2x = Expand[D[U[2], {x, 1}]];

v[6] = 0.5*aa*Y*(Integrate[Expand[(U2x)^2], {x, 0, γ}])
t[6] = 0.5*ρ*
  aa*ω^2*(Integrate[Expand[(U[2])^2], {x, 0, γ}])

U[3] = U[2] /. f -> g;
U[4] = U[2] /. f -> h;

varbar3 = varbar2 /. f -> g;
varbar4 = varbar2 /. f -> h;

v[7] = v[6] /. f -> g;
v[8] = v[6] /. f -> h;

t[7] = t[6] /. f -> g;
t[8] = t[6] /. f -> h;

(*construction of lagrangian*)
T = Sum[t[i], {i, 8}];
V = Sum[v[i], {i, 8}];

n = 3;

dispcon1 = 
  Total[Table[
    Subscript[λ, 
     i]*((W[1] /. x -> z[i]) - (U[i + 1] /. x -> γ)), {i, 1, 
     n}]];

dispcon2 = 
  Total[Table[
    Subscript[α, 
     i]*((U[1] /. x -> z[i]) - (W[i + 1] /. x -> γ)), {i, 1, 
     n}]];

slopcon = 
 Total[Table[
   Subscript[β, 
    i]*(((D[W[1], {x, 1}] /. x -> (z[i] - 0.001))) - (D[
         W[i + 1], {x, 1}] /. x -> (γ - 0.001))), {i, 1, n}]]

mp1 = Table[Subscript[λ, i], {i, 1, n}];
mp2 = Table[Subscript[α, i], {i, 1, n}];
mp3 = Table[Subscript[β, i], {i, 1, n}];


varbeam = {varbeam1, varbeam2, varbeam3, varbeam4};
varbar = {varbar1, varbar2, varbar3, varbar4};
var = Flatten[{varbeam, varbar, mp1, mp2, mp3}]

Lg = (T - V) + dispcon1 + dispcon2 + slopcon
eq = Table[D[Lg, {var[[i]], 1}], {i, 1, Length[var]}]
Rarz = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
MatrixForm[Rarz]
Dimensions[Rarz]
MatrixRank[Rarz]

KK={{-60791.7+59.293 \[Omega]^2,33131.3 -32.3121 \[Omega]^2,-49703.4+48.4699 \[Omega]^2,-12696.1+12.3799 \[Omega]^2,-57627.2+56.2044 \[Omega]^2,-45040.+43.9278 \[Omega]^2,53117.9 -51.8005 \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0845505,0.295078,0.571644,0,0,0,0.15807,0.252636,0.292666},{33131.3 -32.3121 \[Omega]^2,-43827.9+18.0728 \[Omega]^2,101941. -28.3429 \[Omega]^2,180540. -11.1974 \[Omega]^2,68757.3 -31.5221 \[Omega]^2,-13364.7-23.5277 \[Omega]^2,13128.4 +27.0319 \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-8.58621*10^-6,-0.109637,-0.308332,0,0,0,-0.040633,-0.16584,-0.221082},{-49703.4+48.4699 \[Omega]^2,101941. -28.3429 \[Omega]^2,-388012.+48.0337 \[Omega]^2,-789993.+29.6033 \[Omega]^2,-204194.+49.7827 \[Omega]^2,21551. +34.4922 \[Omega]^2,-170854.-37.0396 \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-0.0620549,0.000031888,0.42919,0,0,0,-0.0614558,0.244385,0.558652},{-12696.1+12.3799 \[Omega]^2,180540. -11.1974 \[Omega]^2,-789993.+29.6033 \[Omega]^2,-1.83745*10^6+47.8105 \[Omega]^2,-361513.+20.5982 \[Omega]^2,88603.9 +6.01626 \[Omega]^2,-490379.+1.50844 \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-0.286703,-0.475469,0.0000313999,0,0,0,-0.389932,0.111191,0.809008},{-57627.2+56.2044 \[Omega]^2,68757.3 -31.5221 \[Omega]^2,-204194.+49.7827 \[Omega]^2,-361513.+20.5982 \[Omega]^2,-174216.+55.0447 \[Omega]^2,18639.3 +40.9218 \[Omega]^2,-40415.4-46.6992 \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0143787,0.170873,0.530911,0,0,0,0.0000863559,0.284636,0.411589},{-45040.+43.9278 \[Omega]^2,-13364.7-23.5277 \[Omega]^2,21551. +34.4922 \[Omega]^2,88603.9 +6.01626 \[Omega]^2,18639.3 +40.9218 \[Omega]^2,-268094.+33.1842 \[Omega]^2,36321.5 -39.1733 \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.131648,0.259136,0.394811,0,0,0,0.194914,0.000374931,0.227678},{53117.9 -51.8005 \[Omega]^2,13128.4 +27.0319 \[Omega]^2,-170854.-37.0396 \[Omega]^2,-490379.+1.50844 \[Omega]^2,-40415.4-46.6992 \[Omega]^2,36321.5 -39.1733 \[Omega]^2,-214042.+48.6271 \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-0.147084,-0.405758,-0.533789,0,0,0,-0.247494,-0.228637,-0.000326481},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2.57548*10^6+156.999 \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.99999,0,0,1.3765,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2.57548*10^6+156.999 \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.99999,0,0,1.3765,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2.57548*10^6+156.999 \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.99999,0,0,1.3765},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-6.1685*10^8+157. \[Omega]^2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.382683,0.707107,0.92388,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.2337*10^9+78.5 \[Omega]^2,0,0,-1.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.2337*10^9+78.5 \[Omega]^2,0,0,-1.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.2337*10^9+78.5 \[Omega]^2,0,0,-1.,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0.0845505,-8.58621*10^-6,-0.0620549,-0.286703,0.0143787,0.131648,-0.147084,0,0,0,0,-1.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0.295078,-0.109637,0.000031888,-0.475469,0.170873,0.259136,-0.405758,0,0,0,0,0,-1.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0.571644,-0.308332,0.42919,0.0000313999,0.530911,0.394811,-0.533789,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.99999,0,0,0.382683,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.99999,0,0.707107,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.99999,0.92388,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0.15807,-0.040633,-0.0614558,-0.389932,0.0000863559,0.194914,-0.247494,1.3765,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0.252636,-0.16584,0.244385,0.111191,0.284636,0.000374931,-0.228637,0,1.3765,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0.292666,-0.221082,0.558652,0.809008,0.411589,0.227678,-0.000326481,0,0,1.3765,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}
```

[image]

Comment: Look at `#.First[NullSpace[Rarz]] & /@ Rarz`. They should all be zero for it to be full rank (assuming it's supposed to be orthogonal?). Then look at `{First[NullSpace[Rarz]], Rarz[[5]]} // MatrixForm`. You can see the problem is the 5th row in your matrix and I think the coefficients `{... 0.382683, 0.707107, 0.92388 ...}` corresponding to $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$. The small value of 10^-16 suggests a precision problem. Perhaps your values `beta1 = {1.8751, 4.69409, 7.85476, 10.9955, 14.1372, 17.2788};` are too low precision?

Comment: 1.So what changes I have to make in my code such that I get the full rank? 
2. Also the matrix `KK` is full rank still the determinant is zero why?

Comment: I tried changing all your numbers to rationals and it didn't help but made the rank calculation too slow to complete. I'm afraid I'm running out of ideas and I don't know the domain well enough.

Comment: Let evaluate `MatrixRank[Rarz/. \[Omega] -> RandomReal[]]]`. It give us 8, not 16. It means that there are 8 equations only, not 17 as expected.